# pass integers into array from argv in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I want to pass some integer values into an array via sys.argv, but I get a TypeError.
how can I pass integers into my array, from the argv list? Must I do an explicit conversion?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from array import array
import serial, sys

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
a=array('i',(0 for i in range(1, 3)))

a.append(sys.argv[1])
a.append(sys.argv[2])
a.append(sys.argv[3])

print(a.range(0-2))
```

Here is the Error:

```
$ ./a.py 2 3 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./a.py", line 8, in <module>
    a.append(sys.argv[1])
TypeError: an integer is required
```

I get that array('i') is an array of ints, and that sys.argv is a list item.
I just dont know how to get sys.argv to become an int.

Comment: I don't know what you expect `a.range(0-2)` to do, but the rest can be done in one line: `a = array('i', map(int, sys.argv[1:4]))`. Python is **strongly typed**, it doesn't do implicit conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
a.append(sys.argv[1])
a.append(sys.argv[2])
a.append(sys.argv[3])
```

with:

```
a.append(int(sys.argv[1]))
a.append(int(sys.argv[2]))
a.append(int(sys.argv[3]))
```

and this:

```
print(a.range(0-2))
```

with:

```
print(a[0:2]) # or print(a)
```

otherwise it will throw another error.